# Pullbacks of universal covering space to CW complex isomorphic iff maps are freely homotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces, cw-complexes, principal-bundles

Let $G$ be a discrete topological group that acts freely and properly discontinuously on a space $EG$ which is assumed to be contractible and locally path-connected. We then form the so-called classifying space as the orbit space $BG=EG/G$ and yield a covering projection $p\colon EG\rightarrow BG$, which may also be viewed as a principal $G$-bundle.

I want to prove that if $X$ is a connected $CW$ complex with one 0-cell, and $f,g$ are maps $(X,x_0)\rightarrow (BG,b_0)$, then $f^*EG$ and $g^*EG$ are isomorphic $G$-bundles if and only if the maps $f$ and $g$ are freely homotopic.

I've thought of this: If the bundles are isomorphic, then it suffices to show that $f_\#=g_\#$ since there is a bijection $[X,BG]_*\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1(X,x_0),G)$ given by $[f]\mapsto \phi\circ f_\#$. Here $\phi$ is any (a-priori given) isomorphism between $\pi_1(BG,b_0)$ and $G$ and $[X,BG]_*$ denotes the family of classes of homotopic maps $X\rightarrow BG$. I got stuck here, so now I'm searching for ideas.

I haven't been able to tackle the other direction either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $L:f^*EG\cong g^*EG$ as $G$-bundles over $X$.

They are also covering spaces, and this must be an isomorphism of coverings.

In particular, let $x_0$ be the $0$-cell of $X$ (or in fact, any chosen basepoint), then $L$ induces a bijection on the fibers $p^{-1}(x_0)\to q^{-1}(x_0)$, where $p:f^*EG\to X, q: g^*EG\to X$ are the structure maps.

This bijection is a bijection of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-sets (this is general covering space theory), and $G$-sets (because $L$ is a morphism of $G$-bundles)

But now, as $G$-sets, both $p^{-1}(x_0)$ and $q^{-1}(x_0)$ are isomorphic to $G$ (which is the fiber of $EG\to BG$) with the regular action, so that this map is necessarily of the form $g\mapsto L(e)g$.

Saying that it's a map of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-sets then implies the following equation :
$$L(e)f_*(\alpha)g= g_*(\alpha) L(e)g$$

for all $\alpha\in \pi_1(X,x_0), g\in G$

Taking $g=e$, we get $L(e)f_*(\alpha)L(e)^{-1} = g_*(\alpha)$, i.e. $f_*$ and $g_*$ are conjugate.

Finally, note that $[X,BG]_*\cong \hom(\pi_1(X,x_0),G)$, but those are pointed-homotopy classes of pointed maps $X\to BG$. If you mod out the RHS by conjugation in $G$, it amounts on the LHS to projecting to unpointed-homotopy classes : $[X,BG]_*\to [X,BG]$

(this is an exercise : if $X,Y$ are nice pointed spaces, then $\pi_1(Y)$ acts on $[X,Y]_*$, and the quotient is exactly $[X,Y]$; you then just need to check that the action of $\pi_1(BG)\cong G$ on $[X,BG]_*$ corresponds to the action of $G$ on $\hom(\pi_1(X),G)$ by conjugation)

It follows that $f,g$ are the same element in $[X,BG]$, that is, they are freely homotopic.

The converse either follows from a very general statement :

> If $X,Y$ are nice spaces, $P\to Y$ is a nice bundle, then whenever $f,g : X\to Y$ are homotopic, $f^*P\cong g^*P$

Or you can also prove it in this specific case by noting that associating to a covering space its fiber over the basepoint is an equivalence between covering spaces and $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-sets.

If the maps are freely homotopic, they'll induce conjugate morphisms on $\pi_1$, hence (by the above essentially) isomorphic $\pi_1(X,x_0)\times G^{op}$-sets, hence isomorphic $G^{op}$-objects in covering spaces, hence finally, isomorphic $G$-bundles.

So the proof of the converse depends on what you already know regarding covering spaces and bundles.

Comment: In the 4th and 5th paragraph, when saying that the fibres are $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-sets and $G$-sets, you've implicitly used a trivialization of the fibre (i.e. that it is isomorphic to $G$), correct?

Comment: No, I've used a trivialization only to express the isomorphism. The fact that they're $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-sets is just a general fact from covering space theory, independently of trivialization; and the fact that they're $G$-sets just follows from the fact that $f^*EG$ and $g^*EG$ are $G$-bundles : a $G$-bundle, by definition, has a right $G$-action.

Comment: That's what I meant -- you represented an element of $p^{-1}(x_0)$ as $g$, hence using a trivialization. My next question is: why is the map $g\mapsto L(e)g$ you've written in this trivialization $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-equivariant?

Comment: Ah then yes, you're right ! This map is $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-equivariant because it's induced by a map of covering spaces; if you have two covering spaces $p: Y\to X,  q: Z\to X$ and a morpism $f: Y\to Z$ such that $q\circ f = p$ ( a morphism of covering spaces), it automatically induces a $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-equivariant map $p^{-1}(x_0)\to q^{-1}(x_0)$.

Comment: Further question: what is $G^{op}$?

Comment: Also, for the converse implication, assume no knowledge of the general theory of bundles. An intermediate result in proving the converse is showing that if $G$ acts on some $Y$ freely and prop. discon. with $Y/G=X$, then there exists a map $f\colon (X,x_0)\rightarrow (BG,b_0)$ such that $Y$ and $f^*EG$ are isomorphic $G$-spaces. But this should also be established.

Comment: $G^{op}$ is the opposite group of $G$, defined by $x\times y := yx$ (where the latter is the multiplication of $G$). I just used it because a right action of $G$ can be encoded as a left action of $G^{op}$, and for $G$-bundles we use right actions.

Comment: Well as I explained, for the converse you can also use covering theory rather than bundle theory

Comment: I kindly ask you to review my reasoning regarding the existence of the map in my previous comment: $q\colon Y\rightarrow X=Y/G$ is a regular cover, so  by classification theorem $\exists H\triangleleft \pi_1(X)$ such that $Y\rightarrow X$ is isomorphic to $\tilde X/H\rightarrow X$. Then take $\theta\in \mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1(X),G)$ with $\ker\theta=H$ and then take any representative $f\in[X,BG]_*$ for which $\phi\circ f_\#=\theta$. This seems natural, but I don't see how to establish $f^*EG\cong Y$.

Comment: Covering theory establishes that $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-sets are the same thing as coverings of $X$. This is functorial, so it works if you add structure on both sides, e.g. a right $G$-action. Can you compare the right $G$-action on the fibers of $f^*EG$ and of $Y$ ? And the left $\pi_1(X,x_0)$-action ? Can you conclude from there ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I know how to use your hint. :(

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you have two $G$-bundles over $X$ that are covering spaces, to prove that they're isomorphic $G$-bundles, it suffices to prove that the fibers are isomorphic as $\pi_1(X,x_0)\times G^{op}$-sets